# Mailchimp customised sign-up form is not shown properly in preview mode

Tags: html, forms, mailchimp

I am trying to create a sign-up form that is embedded in the newsletter itself in Mailchimp. The problem is that the input fields of the sign-up form are not shown in the final newsletter. I am wondering if anyone could help me to fix this problem.

Here is the HTML code of the sign-up form I used.

```html
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-10_7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
 #mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
 /* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
    We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
</style>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="//m-yes.us13.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=2d7ba0803d6e5c002cbbd6fa9&amp;id=294842cda0" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">
 <h2>Subscribe to our mailing list</h2>
<div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
 <label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address  <span class="asterisk">*</span>
</label>
 <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
 <label for="mce-FNAME">First Name </label>
 <input type="text" value="" name="FNAME" class="" id="mce-FNAME">
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
 <label for="mce-LNAME">Last Name </label>
 <input type="text" value="" name="LNAME" class="" id="mce-LNAME">
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
 <label for="mce-MMERGE3">Organisation </label>
 <input type="text" value="" name="MMERGE3" class="" id="mce-MMERGE3">
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
 <label for="mce-MMERGE4">Job Title </label>
 <input type="text" value="" name="MMERGE4" class="" id="mce-MMERGE4">
</div>
<div class="mc-field-group">
 <label for="mce-MMERGE5">Phone Number </label>
 <input type="text" value="" name="MMERGE5" class="" id="mce-MMERGE5">
</div>
 <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
  <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
  <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
 </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_2d7ba0803d6e5c002cbbd6fa9_294842cda0" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
    <div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>

<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
```

After inserting this block of code into the newsletter, the form looks just fine. But in the preview mode, all the input fields of the form are gone.

What do I need to modify the HTML code to let the input fields display correctly in the preview mode?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that referencing a stylesheet in email isn't going to work, everything has to be inline.

I don't know that the input field (or post request, for that matter) is supported either.

Why not just put the form in a webpage and reference it from the message?

Comment: Thank you. I have ditched the stylesheet reference and embedded the css codes with the HTML codes. But the problem still exists: all the input fields are not interactive and the subscribe button is not shown. I reckon this is because the newsletter does not support the form tag?

Comment: The reason why we are not referencing to a new webpage is that we think the embedded form could be more convenient to the subscribers.